# Remove characters in a line with sed

Tags: string, bash, unix, sed

Let's suppose I have the following string:

```
variable number of characters -> information information information WORD: info
```

How can I get rid of everything before 'information' and after the last 'information' strings and also How can I get 'info' (remove everything before '->' and the space, and then everything before 'WORD:' and the space bar). Eg.

```
var1="information information information"
var2="info"
```

Also I'd like to learn more about 'sed', I've tried searching the web for some objective articles but I didn't find any. If you have a link to a good article I would appreciate if you share it with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For sed 1: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html and 2: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash has a built-in regular expression operator `=~`. Matches are stored in the `BASH_REMATCH` (**r**eg**e**x **m**atch) array.

```
regex='^.* -> (.*) WORD: (.*)$'

if [[ $string =~ $regex ]]; then
    var1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    var2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed one liners and sed FAQ at Eric Pement's page are useful.

http://www.pement.org/sed/index.htm